# Google Cloud Bigtable deployment errors with Managed VMs

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to deploy [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vm-gae) to Google Cloud. I'm following the exact instructions,

When I go to Cloud Console -> App Engine -> versions, I did see a new version deployed, but the size of the version is 0, and going to the module url returns 503 server error even after I waited 30 minutes.

```
Error: Server Error The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Since I didn't modify anything in the example except the `PROJECT_ID`, `CLUSTER_UNIQUE_ID`, etc. What could be the problem here?

Comment: mvn clean gcloud:deploy -Dbigtable.projectID=myProject -Dbigtable.clusterID=myCluster -Dbigtable.zone=myZone     -- I'll go through this in the next hour and see if something has changed.

Comment: It looks like something broke, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've updated the sample.

Comment: @RohitNigam – could you please try it out again and confirm whether or not this is still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue. I resolved it by doing the following changes:

1. Within web.xml:

`<servlet>
       <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloServlet        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

2. Added an index.html file within WebApp folder.
3. Within pom.xml, added the following:

   `<dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>`